# How to use MusiXTeX to draw chord brackets at the right side of chord?

Tags: latex, tex, xelatex

I am using MusiXTeX but have found that it's official document haven't said anything about placing a right-side bracket onto a chord. Could anyone please tell me how to achieve it?
(If I use left-side bracket, it could across through those accidental markers. Nobody want to see that happen.)

[image: image description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this code anywhere before and try using `\rbracket` instead of `\bracket`.

```
\makeatletter
\def\rbracket#1#2{\y@iv#2\internote \advance\y@iv\tw@\internote
  \inhgetn@i#1\relax\pl@base \advance\y@i-1\h@lf\internote
  \raise\y@i\rlap{\uplap{\offinterlineskip\hbox{\roffset{1.5}{\mxsps\@xxvii}}%
\hbox{\roffset2{\vrule\@height\y@iv}}\hbox{\roffset{1.5}{\mxsps\@xxvii}}}}}
\makeatother
```